# Calculations with a Nested if statement

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am working on a program that has nested if and my math is correct the only thing is that the correct output is not printing. I do not know where I am supposed to put the line for the output in the first if, nested if or both lines? The Values I am putting in for a test is imported bottle of perfume for 27.99. The output should be 32.19 and I am getting 34.99.

```
public class SalesTax 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Input items for shopping cart
        HashMap<String, String> cart = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> shoppingcart = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // variables
        char done;

        //boolean goods;
        double totalprice = 0.00;
        double taxprice;
        double ftax;

        // Pick items for list.
        do 
        {  
            System.out.print("Please enter an item.");
            String item = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Please enter the price for "+ item + ": ");
            String price = input.nextLine(); 

            double price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
            totalprice += price1; 

            //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
            String price2 = String.valueOf(price1);
            cart.put(item, price2);

            //determine if item will have additional tax
            if (item.contains("music"))
            {
                 price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                taxprice = price1 * .10;

                totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice);

                if (item.contains("imported"))
                {
                     price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                    ftax = price1 * .05;

                    totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax);
                }

                //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
                String newprice2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
                shoppingcart.put(item,newprice2);
            }
            else if(item.contains("bottle"))
            {
                 price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                taxprice = price1 * .10;

                totalprice = (price1 + taxprice);

                if (item.contains("imported"))
                {
                     price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                    ftax = price1 * .05;

                    totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax);
                }

                //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
                String newprice2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
                shoppingcart.put(item,newprice2);
            }
            else if (item.contains("imported"))
            {
                 price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                taxprice = price1 * .05;

                totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice);

                if (item.contains("imported"))
                {
                     price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                    ftax = price1 * .05;

                    totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax);
                }

                //System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
                String newprice2 = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
                shoppingcart.put(item,newprice2);
            }
            else 
            {
                shoppingcart.put(item, price);
            }


            System.out.print("Would you like to continue to add items? (Type Y) for Yes and (Type N) for No.");
            done = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        } while(Character.toUpperCase(done) == 'Y');

       System.out.println("Your cart contains the following at items with tax" + shoppingcart); //+ String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
       System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",totalprice));
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple things: First of all, you should separate your code out into one function that takes in input, and one function that calculates cost. Second of all, it'll be easier to help you if you reduce the code to only what's needed to reproduce (it's not clear if all the if clauses are relevant).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use bigDecimal instead of float or double.

In fact if you try that :

```
double value = 10*0.09;
System.out.println(value);
```

You have :

```
0.8999999999999999
```

Use this method :

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("10");
BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("0.09");
BigDecimal value = value1.multiply(value2);
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding one of the taxes twice :

```
            totalprice = (price1 + taxprice);

            if (item.contains("imported"))
            {
                price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
                ftax = price1 * .05;

                totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax);
            }
```

Should be :

```
            totalprice = (price1 + taxprice);

            if (item.contains("imported"))
            {
                ftax = price1 * .05;
                totalprice = (price1 + taxprice + ftax);
            }
```

Or :

```
            totalprice = (price1 + taxprice);

            if (item.contains("imported"))
            {
                ftax = price1 * .05;
                totalprice = (totalprice + ftax);
            }
```

Oh, and there's no need to parse `price1` from the String again. It already contains the correct value.

Comment: or in the second block: `totalprice = totalprice + ftax`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should structure your code better. I would add a method called 'calculateTax':

```
...
double totalPrice = originalPrice + originalPrice * calculateTax(originalPrice, item);
String newprice = String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", totalprice));
shoppingcart.put(item,newprice);
...


public double calculateTax(double originalPrice, String item){
  double tax = 0.0;

  if(item.contains("music")){
    tax += originalPrice * O.1;
  }
  if(item.contains("bottle")){
    tax += originalPrice * O.1;
  }
  if(item.contains("imported")){
    tax += originalPrice * O.05;
  }
  return tax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake can be found when adding the `taxprice` for a second time.

```
if (item.contains("music"))
{
    totalprice = (price1 + taxprice);
    ...

    if (item.contains("imported"))
    {
        ...

        totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax); // <- You've already added the taxprice
    }

    ...
}
```

So:

```
totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax);
```

should be changed to

```
totalprice = (totalprice + ftax);

// (Or shorter)
totalprice += ftax;
```

---

Also, some additional suggestions:

**`while-loop` or `recursion`:** Instead of using multiple nested ifs, use a while loop or recursion with a single if, else-if, else case (or `switch-case`). From the code I can see you're pretty new to programming, but having duplicated code is never what you would want. :)

**try-catches:** Also, I would use a try-catch around the `Double.parseDouble(...);`, in case something is entered which isn't parse-able to double (like some random letters):

```
try{
    price1 = Double.parseDouble(price);
}
catch(ParseException ex){
    price1 = 0.00;
}
```

**BigDecimals:** This is also pretty new to me myself, but a few weeks back I've heard doubles and floats are really bad when working with currencies. A post about this with more information can be found [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2012/02/java-mistake-1-using-float-and-double.html) or [here](http://java-performance.info/bigdecimal-vs-double-in-financial-calculations/). Instead, use `BigDecimals`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hi when your input is :

```
imported bottle of perfumes & Price is 27.99
```

It is entering in second if else condition i.e (else if(item.contains("bottle")))

And if you calculate based on that ans will be 34.99 only.

I think you are calculating based on 3rd if else.

Ex:

```
Please enter an item: imported bottle of perfumes
Enter the price for imported bottle of perfumes: 27.99
```

Then

```
taxprice:2.799
totalprice:30.788999999999998
ftax:1.3995
totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax);
i.e totalprice: 34.99 only and its correct.
```

But if your input is like this:

```
Please enter an item: imported perfumes
Enter the price for imported bottle of perfumes: 27.99
```

Then

```
taxprice:1.399
totalprice:29.389499999999998
ftax:1.3995
totalprice = (totalprice + taxprice + ftax)
i.e totalprice: = 32.19
```

Hope you got the mistake, cross check with input values.